# Newtons Craddle using javascript . Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined index.js.90

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I started to work on a project to make a newton's cradle using HTML, CSS, JavaScript.
after installing npm packages like d3-force-bounce, d3-drag, d3-force-constant. I am not able to get a responsive cradle. I feel like the error is somehow linked to this line:

```
.on("drag", d => { d.fx = d3.event.x; d.fy = d3.event.y; })
```

I get the error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

I'll attach the index.js file code here.

```
function ballDigest() {
    let ball = ballsG.selectAll('circle.ball').data(balls);

    ball.exit().remove();

    ball.merge(
        ball.enter().append('circle')
            .classed('ball', true)
            .attr('r', BALL_RADIUS)
            .attr('fill', 'url(#sphere-gradient)')
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", d => { d.fx = d.x; d.fy = d.y; })
                .on("drag", d => { d.fx = d3.event.x; d.fy = d3.event.y; })
                .on("end", d => { d.fx = null; d.fy = null; })
            )
    )
        .attr('cx', d => d.x)
        .attr('cy', d => d.y);
}
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of d3-drag?

Comment: @RodrigoDivino Yes , I am using the latest version of d3-drag.